# Jquery looping through a single form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through a specific form on my page.  I basically want to disable or set readonly on every single field once the page loads.

I think I could construct the for each loop but I'm not sure how to make it specify it in the form on the page so it doens't touch the inputs in my header etc.

Here is a small version of my form:

```
<form id="account_information" class="stdform stdform2" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname" class="smallinput" />
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lastname" class="smallinput" />
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {

  $('form#account_information :input').prop('disabled', true).prop('readonly', true);

})
```

Comment: Using `[type=text]` is not the best solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the very quick and correct answer every options seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

```
$(function() {
    $("#account_information :input")
        .prop("disabled", true)     // To disable
        .prop("readonly", true);    // To set readonly
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xdpC8/

Answer (score 2):

Set all inputs to disabled:

```
$(function() {
  $('#account_information :input').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/9VAKB/